# How to use async map series in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using async map series to manipulate an array.

```
exports.MultiChannelInvoke = async function (bulkUploadArray) {
  async.mapSeries(bulkUploadArray, async function (array, cb) {
    let ap = array[0]
    let apArray = ['PL', 'A', 'J', 'V', 'I'];

    if (!apArray.includes(ap)) {  // For Array's first value it is KL & it is getting inside this loop
      //some manipulation
    }
    else {
      //some manipulation
    }
  }, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      masterResult = { message: 'Failed During async Map', errorMessage: err }

    } else {
      let mongoData = batch;
      uploadsummary.create(mongoData)
      masterResult = { FinalResults: results }

    }
  })

  return masterResult
}
```

My bulkupload Array will be like follow:

```
[
  [
    "KL",
    {
      "ms": "2147766904",
      "desc": "APP-LIC JEEVAN POLICY,7878787878,30/01/19",
      "ur": "DNDSER6911744",
      "tap": "TA",
      "tapupdate": [ "Array" ]
    }
  ],
  [
    'PL',
    {
      ms: '3147766904',
      desc: 'APP-LIC JEEVAN POLICY,9916957781,30/01/19',
      ur: 'DNDSER6911745',
      tap: 'TA',
      tapupdate: [ Array ]
    }
  ]
]
```

So as per my bulkupload array first value is KL & it is getting inside the first if loop.(which i have mentioned in comments in the code). So after getting inside & doing manipulation, it is not considering the second array value. After finishing the manipulation for first value, it is directly returning the result. Can anybody please tell me what Im doing wrong? Or should I not use async map series. Please suggest me.

Comment: You are not calling callback `cb();` after "some manipulation". That's how you tell `mapSeries` function to process next item.

Comment: ^if you are using `async-await` you don't have to call the `cb()` function. Just return the value.

Comment: If you're using promises in any capacity, you might as well avoid the async library entirely since they're fulfilling (no pun intended) the same purpose. They tend not to complement each other well anyway, since the library is callback-based and async/await is promise-based...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, making a function `async-await` doesn't auto-magically returns the value AFTER everything is processed. `return masterResult` will be executed before `async.mapSeries` you need to make a promise and return it.

Also, if you are using `async-await` inside `async.js` you need to return the data from the async function to be considered as result.

Here is a version incorporating what I told above:

```
const MultiChannelInvoke = function (bulkUploadArray) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => { //make promise
    async.mapSeries(bulkUploadArray, async function (array) { //no cb required
      let ap = array[0]
      let apArray = ['PL', 'A', 'J', 'V', 'I'];

      if (!apArray.includes(ap)) {  // For Array's first value it is KL & it is getting inside this loop
        return 'IF!'
      }
      else {
        return 'ELSE';
      }
    }, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        rej({ message: 'Failed During async Map', errorMessage: err }); //reject
      } else {
        res(results); //resolve
      }
    })
  })
}


MultiChannelInvoke([['KL',
  {
    ms: '2147766904',
    desc: 'APP-LIC JEEVAN POLICY,7878787878,30/01/19',
    ur: 'DNDSER6911744',
    tap: 'TA',
    tapupdate: [Array]
  }],
['PL',
  {
    ms: '3147766904',
    desc: 'APP-LIC JEEVAN POLICY,9916957781,30/01/19',
    ur: 'DNDSER6911745',
    tap: 'TA',
    tapupdate: [Array]
  }]]).then(console.dir);
```

Output:
`[ 'IF!', 'ELSE' ]`